# SQL Copy only data from table1 where it doesnt exist in table 2?

Tags: sql, select

I have 2 sql tables and I would like to merge into 1. I would like to only copy the rows where the column "Item" from table 1 does not exist in table 2. Any Ideas?

```
Select Item
into new table2
from table1
where????
```

Comment: RDBMS flavour please..

Comment: Break it into steps.  How would you write a select statement to give you the data you wanted.  Now take the select statement and make it a `create table as` or an insert into `select from`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming SQL Server given the `SELECT INTO` in your question:

Using your sample query to populate a new table with only records from `Table1` where the `item` value wasn't in `Table2`:

```
SELECT a.Item 
INTO new_table2
FROM table1 a
LEFT JOIN Table2 b
  ON a.item = b.item
WHERE b.item IS NULL
```

If you didn't want a new table and just want to add to `Table2` the records from `Table1` that aren't already there:

```
INSERT INTO Table2 (Item) 
SELECT a.Item
FROM table1 a
LEFT JOIN Table2 b
  ON a.item = b.item
WHERE b.item IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO table2(col1, col2, col3) -- add the respective columns here
SELECT col1, col2, col3
FROM table1 A
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM table2
                 WHERE Item = A.Item)
```